# Query many-to-many ef core relationship

Tags: ef-core-3.1

I have following classes

```cs
    public class Book
    {
        public string BookId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        // Relationships
        public ICollection<BookCategory> CategoriesLink { get; set; }
    }

    public class BookCategory
    {
        public string BookId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryId { get; set; }

        public Book Book { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public string CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BookCategory> BooksLink { get; set; } 
    }
```

I am not sure how to get all the `Book`s for the given `Category`. I am using EFCore 3.1. I tried following, but not sure if it is efficient.

```cs
    return context.Categories
        .Include(x => x.BooksLink)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Book)
        .Where(x => x.CategoryId == category)
        .SelectMany(x=>x.BooksLink.Select(y=>y.Book))
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to performance reasons it is not adviced to use the .Include method.

For a better query I would use this linq

```
from book in context.book
 join bookCatJoin in context.BookCategory on book.id equals bookCatJoin.BookId
 join category in context.Category.Where(e=>e.Name=="crime") on bookCatJoin.categoryId equals category.CategoryId
 select book;
```

This query works with better performance than includes. Because each include makes a left join with the whole table.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data
Docs for .Include highlights this recommendation